# Algorithm to organize/insert dates sequentially

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, date

I need to build an algorithm that can look at X number of records which have overlapping dates in them and organize and re-insert those date values in a chronological sequence.
E.g.: 
The table has a record like this:

```
Start Date  End Date    Value

1/1/2019    12/31/2099  10
```

When a new record like this is inserted:

```
5/1/2019    5/31/2019   25
```

The algorithm should organize the records like this and insert it into a new table:

```
1/1/2019    4/30/2019   10
5/1/2019    5/31/2019   25
6/1/2019    12/31/2099  10
```

The original table should not be modified, i.e. no reinserting/reordering of records in that original table.

Any tips on the most efficient way to accomplish this? Not looking for database specific solutions.. programming only.
Thanks!

Comment: What does "like this" actually mean?  Those dates do not overlap.

Comment: the new record has start and end dates that occur in between the start and end dates of the original record.

Comment: to do it programmatically, you can create a class with start,end date and value, then save your records into an container in memory. then add comparators to sort by the field you want (either sort by start, end date or by value).

Comment: You might not be aware but how dates are spelled out differs throughout the world.  In Germany it's common to write them as DD.MM.YYYY while in the US you will find MM/DD YYYY.  There is, however, a universal way of writing a date which also makes it sortable, and that's why it also is an ISO standard: YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601).  You can make life easier for everybody by sticking to this notation.

Answer (score 0):

Start by working out the ways that dates can overlap. Off the top of my head ways periods could overlap are:

- A row with the start date before and the end date after the *start date* of your new row
- A row with the start date before and the end date after the *end date* of your new row
- A row with the start date after the start date of your new row, and the end date before the end date of your new row (the period is completely inside your period)
- A row with the start date before the start date of your new row, and the end date after the end date of your new row (the period is completely around your period)

There may be other possibilities as well, but that group seems about right.

Assuming that the rows in the second table already don't overlap you can query it for the overlapping rows relatively easily, then you can calculate the new group of dates to use and update your second table. Write lots of unit tests for the calculation.

Be aware that this will be a concurrency minefield (depending on the sort of application you're doing this in). If two users can submit a new row at the same time then you'll need some way to be sure that the read, calculation and update are one atomic action, otherwise your second table is going to get inconsistent pretty fast.